# How do you put a border around a UITableViewCell's contentView? (for testing)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

what's the code to put a border around a UITableViewCell's contentView?   (for testing)

If not possible why is this?  (for my learning)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have you tried using `contentView`'s underlying `CALayer`? Try something like this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)someAppropriateMethod
{
    [self.myTableViewCell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    [self.myTableViewCell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: I was actually interested in the view size of the "contentView" of the cell, as opposed to the cell?  Or are you saying that when you reference the layer of the cell, you effeccively get the view of the cell's content view returned?     Also in XCode I get a "methodNotFound" warning for the setBorderColor, which is strange, was it works for me with other views?

Comment: No no, you can do the same for the content view (as in Chown's answer). I did actually originally write my answer for the `contentView`, but missed it in the code. I'll put it back to the contentView version :)

Comment: thanks - no ideas why the "setBorderColor" isn't available to me for these objects?  They are for other views, and I've used this technique before, however when I got to the contentView here it wouldn't work hence why I posted?

Comment: solved with this answer + chown's advise re "Make sure to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>"

Comment: If you're using an accessory view, the border shows up between the contentView and the accessoryView too, which looks tacky.

Comment: I don't think messing with layer in UITableViewCell is a good idea, will result in lags while scrolling.

Comment: @atulkhatri That depends on your cell's content, but generally speaking simply adding a border to a layer should have a minimal effect on rendering performance. That aside, the question was explicitly regarding using this for testing, not in a shipping app.

Answer (score 6):

You could also apply it to the cells contentView loke so:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)someAppropriateMethod {
    myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: --> with tableCell only write:
cell.layer.borderWidth = 2;
cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4:

```
myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)someAppropriateMethod {
    myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
}
```